# WooCommerce: How Can A Product Weight Be Returned Using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, woocommerce, feed

I am setting up a Google Merchant Feed, and one of the requirements is to include a shipping weight of the product. I am using this tutorial: http://www.binaryforest.com/woocommerce-google-product-feed/

How can the product weight be returned by php into the xml?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

functions.php:

```
//Define the product feed php page
function products_feed_rss2() {
 $rss_template = get_template_directory() . '/product-feed.php';
 load_template ( $rss_template );
}

//Add the product feed RSS
add_action('do_feed_products', 'products_feed_rss2', 10, 1);

//Update the Rerewrite rules
add_action('init', 'my_add_product_feed');

//function to add the rewrite rules
function my_rewrite_product_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
 $new_rules = array(
 'feed/(.+)' => 'index.php?feed='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
 );
 $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

//add the rewrite rule
function my_add_product_feed( ) {
 global $wp_rewrite;
 add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_product_rules');
 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

product-feed.php

```
<?php
/**
 * RSS2 Feed Template for displaying RSS2 Posts feed.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

header('Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type('rss-http') . '; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'), true);
$more = 1;

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>'; ?>

<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
    xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
    <?php do_action('rss2_ns'); ?>
>

<channel>
    <title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); wp_title_rss(); ?></title>
    <atom:link href="<?php self_link(); ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>
    <description>Skin care products for rosacea sufferers</description>
    <lastBuildDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), false); ?></lastBuildDate>
    <language><?php bloginfo_rss( 'language' ); ?></language>
    <sy:updatePeriod><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_period', 'hourly' ); ?></sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_frequency', '1' ); ?></sy:updateFrequency>
    <?php do_action('rss2_head'); ?>
    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 999 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product;
    ?>
    <item>
        <title><?php the_title_rss() ?></title>
        <link><?php the_permalink_rss() ?></link>
        <g:image_link><?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ) ?></g:image_link>
        <g:price><?php echo $product->price ?></g:price>
        <g:condition>new</g:condition>
        <g:id><?php echo $id; ?></g:id>
        <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
        <g:google_product_category>Health &amp; Beauty &gt; Health Care &gt; Fitness &amp; Nutrition &gt; Vitamins &amp; Supplements </g:google_product_category>
        <g:gtin><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_cpf_upc', true ); ?></g:gtin>
        <g:brand><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_cpf_brand', true ); ?></g:brand>
<?php if (get_option('rss_use_excerpt')) : ?>
        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
<?php else : ?>
        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php rss_enclosure(); ?>
    <?php do_action('rss2_item'); ?>
    </item>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working answer:

```
<g:shipping_weight><?php echo $product->weight ?></g:shipping_weight>
```